# Why am i getting NoneType object error inside the for loop?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(0, len(files)):
    t=resized_ imgs[i].mean()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mean'

Comment: Do you actually have a space character between the `resized_` and `imgs` in your code, or is this a copy-paste error. If just a copy-paste error, we need to know what kinds of data you have put into `resized_imgs`.

Answer (score 0):

`resized_ imgs[i]` returned an unexpected results !

Check this point .

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

The field may contain None value. Therefore it can't compute properly whenever it gets None value. So put this block under try statement.

```
for i in range(0, len(files)):
   try:
      t=resized_imgs[i].mean() 
   except AttributeError:
      print "NONE type"
```